# Salesforce.com - Visualforce and ActiveX

Tags: html, activex, salesforce, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page through which I am trying to access a SDK. It is done using ActiveX control. The VB + JS script that I have runs fine when it is a normal HTML page residing on my desktop. However the same code when incorporated in Visualforce does not work. Does running ActiveX control require uploading any kind of files to Static Resource? My code need not be a Visualforce. If there is any other way I could integrate ActiveX with Salesforce, even that would be fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you need somewhere to host the .cab (or .ocx) file, then you can put that in a static resource, and reference that from your VF code.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using to test? If IE6 it may need you to enable the ActiveX controls.

[If you go to Tools->Internet Options->Security Tab.  Click ‘Custom’ and OK any message.  Then scroll down to ‘Script Active X Controls ….’.  This should be enabled.'](http://community.salesforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/a4j-AJAX-is-null-or-not-an-object-in-Visualforce-page/m-p/116864)